# WPF - Setting caret position using a TouchPoint

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, multi-touch, caret

I am creating a multitouch text editor application and need to place the caret at a certain location in my RichTextBox, where a user touches the screen.

This is what I have (in C#):

```
    txtEditor.CaretPosition = txtEditor.GetPositionFromPoint(e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position, true);
```

Although this line somewhat moves the caret close to the location of the TouchPoint, it is not accurate. The position of the cursor achieved using this line of code is about 10 characters off the actual location (to the right hand side). Could someone please let me know how I can achieve a more accurate result?

Comment: This might sound silly, but have you tried just correcting the position by about 10 characters?  Is it consistently off by the same amount and always to the right?  If so, `txtEditor.CaretPosition = (txtEditor.GetPositionFromPoint(e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position,true)).getPositionAtOffset(10,LogicalDirection.Backward);`

Comment: @ToastyMallows: Yes I tried that but it is a little complicated. I realized that the caret is not just off by about 10 characters horizontally but also a few characters vertically. Anyway, I do not need to use this anymore since I am using a different approach altogether. But thank you!